# How do we define the measure theoretic entropy for an infinite partition?

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy

Let $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ be a probability space. If $\xi = \{A_1, ..., A_k\}$ is a finite partition of $X$, then the measure theoretic entropy is defined as
$$H_\mu(\xi) = -\sum_{i=1}^k \mu(A_i) \; log \; \mu(A_i).$$

How do we define the entropy for an infinite partition? For example, for
$\xi = \{ \{x\} : x \in X \}$?

Comment: If the partition is infinite but countable, the same definition works and is meaningful.  Note that each term is in the sum is $\leq 0$, so the infinite sum is meaningful although it can be $-\infty$.  The entropy of an uncountable partition doesn't make much sense, although it is sometimes defined to be $+\infty$ for mathematical nicety.

Comment: In fact, I want to know how we define the conditional entropy $H_\mu(\xi | f^{-1} \xi)$, when $f : M \to M$ is a non-invertible map on a Riemann manifold and $\xi = \{ \{x\} : x \in M \}$.

Comment: You simply don't define that in general, although it could be meaningful for some atomic measures. But I wonder whether you would then ask about $h_\mu(\xi)$ defined in terms of conditional entropy. One should also note that we never need infinite partitions, finite partitions are quite sufficient.

Comment: @JohnB Countably infinite partitions arise naturally in quite a few contexts, for example: Omri Sarig's construction of infinite Markov partitions for nonuniformly hyperbolic dynamical systems. Uncountably infinite partitions similarly have utility in the theory of dynamical entropy of hyperbolic (uniform or no) systems. For example, once such machinery is in place, the Ledrappier-Young entropy formula relating metric entropy and Lyapunov exponents follows from a few lines. Finite partitions may be sufficient for _defining_ entropy, however.

Comment: @ABlumenthal Good that you know all these examples, but again in all of them we only need finite measurable partitions (either as in Rohklin or not). We are always talking about using them in entropy, right? That's why I say this. Otherwise, we would need countable **Markov** partitions (note that the example by Sarig comes much later then the billiard theory; as you might know there were various attempts that remain unpublished in view of problems with the shadowing properties).

Comment: @ABlumenthal Just complementing my comment, in what respects to the LY seminal work we can define the conditionals using only finite partitions, taking limits on kind of tubes around each foliation. In the limit we would be talking about infinite partitions, but we also don't need them. It is instructive in this respect to read the LY work thinking that we have a uniformly hyperbolic system from the beginning,